# get results of form on the next page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-maps, geocoding

I am using this form to geocode addresses onto a map. Im trying to move the form to a separate page that on submit goes to the page with the map.
I dont know how to get these seperated...any advice on how to separate the form from the map?

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&libraries=places"> </script>
<style>
  #map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin-top: 0.6em;
  }
</style>
<script>
var geocoder;
var map;
  var infowindow;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var loca = new google.maps.LatLng( 33.4987780197 , -117.70713998);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: loca,
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }
  function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
    var request = {
      location: results[0].geometry.location,
      radius: 50000,
      name: 'ski',
      keyword: 'mountain',
      type: ['park']
    };
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
 }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>   
     <form  action="map" method="post">
     <label for="zip">Zip Code: </label>
     <input type = "text" id="address" placeholder = "orange county" autofocus></input>
     <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="codeAddress();" ></input>
     </form>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="text">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to set a name for the field you want to pass to the next page:

```
<input type = "text" id="address" name="address" placeholder = "orange county" autofocus></input>
```

You would need some server code to receive form data. The exact code would depend on your choice of language for this code. 
e.g. for PHP the code to use this on the page that receives it (the one in the action of the form) would be

```
<?php
$address=isset($_POST['address'])?$_POST['address']:'';
?>
```

And then you can use the $address variable in this page.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is passing geocode address result via URI,for example:
the URI of the page with map is: http://exmaple.com/map/   when you return this page, add result with URI,so the URI becomes: http://example.com/map/?address=result and then parse the URI.
Another way, you can use Cross Document Message,when you geocoding address,send message to the parent window.